# Table row background size gets duplicated

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a progressive border on the bottom of a table row to indicate a download progress. Here is what I came up with:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg/225px-Solid_blue.svg.png") no-repeat 0% 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

tr.progress-50 {
  background-size: 50% 1px;
}

tr.progress-25 {
  background-size: 25% 1px;
}

tr.progress-75 {
  background-size: 75% 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Second</th>
      <th>Third</th>
      <th>Fourth</th>
      <th>Fifth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="progress-50">
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
      <td>1.4</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="progress-25">
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td>2.3</td>
      <td>2.4</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="progress-75">
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td>3.2</td>
      <td>3.3</td>
      <td>3.4</td>
      <td>3.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, my tr background styling seems to be applied to the tds.

Why is that? How to avoid this behaviour?

I've checked the possible duplicate answers but nothing solved my issue unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not being able to associate the border of the table row with your background. What is actually happening?

Comment: The red border seems to be applied to the tr, but the the blue background is applied to all tds instead of the tr as I'd like it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to set the background on the `table` instead of `tr`, I can see that Chrome and Firefox render the style on `tr` quite differently, but they look the same if you set it on `table`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/ElfCxIY.png") no-repeat 0% 100%;
  background-size: 50% 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>Fourth</td>
    <td>Fifth</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**

For multiple table rows, you can convert each `tr` to `display: table;`, but that sort of breaks the tabular layout, however it will still work in equal data or cell length, e.g. fixed table layout. And it is still possible to declare the `width` for the cells, just need apply that on every cell in each column.

```css
tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* table-layout: fixed; */
}
tbody tr {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/ElfCxIY.png") no-repeat 0% 100%;
}
.progress-50 {
  background-size: 50% 1px;
}
.progress-25 {
  background-size: 25% 1px;
}
.progress-75 {
  background-size: 75% 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Second</th>
      <th>Third</th>
      <th>Fourth</th>
      <th>Fifth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="progress-50">
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
      <td>1.4</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="progress-25">
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td>2.3</td>
      <td>2.4</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="progress-75">
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td>3.2</td>
      <td>3.3</td>
      <td>3.4</td>
      <td>3.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Example of using `linear-gradient()` instead of background image, with some animations.

```css
tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* table-layout: fixed; */
}
tbody tr {
  background: linear-gradient(blue 50%, blue 50%) no-repeat 0% 100%;
  background-size: 0 1px;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.progress-50 {
  animation-name: p25;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.progress-25 {
  animation-name: p50;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.progress-75 {
  animation-name: p75;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
@keyframes p25 {
  to {
    background-size: 25% 1px;
  }
}
@keyframes p50 {
  to {
    background-size: 50% 1px;
  }
}
@keyframes p75 {
  to {
    background-size: 75% 1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Second</th>
      <th>Third</th>
      <th>Fourth</th>
      <th>Fifth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="progress-50">
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
      <td>1.4</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="progress-25">
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td>2.3</td>
      <td>2.4</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="progress-75">
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td>3.2</td>
      <td>3.3</td>
      <td>3.4</td>
      <td>3.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The thing is that each row would have a different progress value (first row would be 50%, second row 25%, ...)

Comment: @YannBertrand I updated it with a solution for multi rows, let me know.

Comment: Cool! Is there any way to have different-widthed columns? (maybe by using a background color instead of an image)

Comment: @YannBertrand You can set width on any cell in each row, better to do it in every row so it still behaves like a single table. You can use [linear gradient](https://jsfiddle.net/9dovqhwp/) instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Chrome simply ignores the tr background. The only solution for TR background that i found was using inline attributes like:

```
<tr background='url'></tr>
```

Hope you can do it. Please post the solution if you find it

Comment: I think your misunderstood my question. I'd like to have a 1px-height line on the bottom of the row, and make the width of that line change over time

Comment: Actually i understood, but i wasn't capable to find a solution. There are many people with the same problem as you, and they didn't find too. I wish you luck!

Comment: Thank you anyways!